# What is the expected lifecycle of SWINject Graphidentifiers

Tags: swift5, swinject

I'll start my saying that I'm inexperienced with Swinject.

I'm trying to figure out why `Swinject.graphIdentier` instances are constantly growing in my app.

In my case when I enter a ViewController I create **n** instances of `MyClass`.
**n** can be a different amount each time the screen is visited.

When I leave the view controller all instances of `MyClass` are deallocated (proven by observing allocations profiler).

The thing that I don't understand is why instances of `Swinject.graphIdentier` continue to grow.

Should GraphIdentifers in swinject ever be cleanedup and if so how can I do that?

[image]

Below is a stripped down, contrived example of my code.

```
 class MyClass {
    
    }
    
 container.register(MyClass.self) {_ in
        return MyClass()
    }
    //Graph Identifier Count goes up
  func addItems() {
      let newItem = AppAssembler.resolver.resolve(MyClass.self)
      items.append(newItem)
   }
    //Graph Identifier count never goes down
  func removeItems() {
     items.removeAll()
   }
```